# Why can't you suggest tag synonyms without 2,500 Rep?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I was working with a fairly [little used tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chromium-embedded) recently and ran into something annoying. The tag, chromium embedded is referred to more often by its abbreviation CEF. However, CEF was not listed as a tag or synonym. It didn't even think the tag for chromium embedded existed until I found it on a Google search on a topic. I thought I could save another person the annoyance of finding the tag by suggesting a tag synonym, but discovered that isn't possible. I know that if you don't have have the rep to edit a tag wiki you can suggest a tag wiki edit, but was wondering why you can't suggest a tag synonym. Are you suspecting that new users would spam tons on pointless tag synonyms?

**Update**: I have requested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197748/tag-synonym-request-cef-for-chromium-embedded) to add this tag as a synonyms.

**Update**: CEF tag synonym created.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One of the goals of the reputation system is to give people more access to certain features once they've gained enough experience with the system to fully understand how it works.

On the low end of the spectrum, most very new users don't have a clue what Stack Overflow is about, so to avoid those users doing things that aren't good for Stack Overflow, their ability to do certain things is limited.

There's tons of guidelines on how tags work on Stack Overflow, and a new user is likely to not be familiar with them. However, you *can* suggest a tag synonym via meta, as you've done, and if users with greater than 2,500 rep agree, they can get the process started.

In your case, your suggested tag is valuable, and Chromium Embedded is more widely known and recognizable as CEF. I would suggest this tag synonym for you, but even at 14k reputation on Stack Overflow, I still must have at least a +5 score in the tag in order to create the synonym, so maybe one of the moderators can add it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this makes more sense. Maybe you should be ably to suggest a tag synonym if you have the required score but not the rep, but I could see how that would be confusing

Comment: In your case, you suggest a valuable tag, but some tags are too broad or too narrow and just serve to clutter up the list of tags. For instance, the "programming" tag is one of the worst examples I can think of of a tag we really don't need. :)  Hope this helps!

Comment: @minitech - The thing is, I know better than that. I never see those things while I'm typing, only afterwards. :)  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Heh, no problem. That’s how it always is. (Though obviously *I* never misuse “it’s”. That would be bad. `;)`)

Comment: Asked for tag synonym here: [Tag Synonym Request: CEF for Chromium-Embedded](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197748/tag-synonym-request-cef-for-chromium-embedded).