# Tag Synonym Request: CEF for Chromium-Embedded

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

[Chromium Embedded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chromium-embedded) is called by its abbreviation CEF than its actual name. I was wondering if anyone would be willing to create a tag synonym for it. Thanks! If you have any feedback be sure to let me know. I was suggested [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197739/why-cant-you-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-2-500-rep) to ask in meta to see if anybody experienced with CEF agrees with me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That synonym already exists. See its [tag synonym page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/chromium-embedded/synonyms). It was created 2 hours ago by minitech.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I started asking about what to do about this 2 hours ago and I guess someone did something.

Comment: You SE mods really are precognitive (but why don't you have the badge)?!?